# What is the best way to handle feed in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a situation, where I downloaded json string from server, like twitter or facebook or dropbox etc.

How should I store these data, so the data can be viewed during offline?

I implemented using SQLite, but worry if it is heavy for this job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. Store in to the SQLite Database
2. Store the JSON/XML file locally and parse it when you need to display it.

I would suggest storing it in the database too.